# How do I get bootcamp to properly pay attention to the option key?

Tags: windows, mac-osx, bootcamp

I have bootcamp installed, and it has worked fine (for months) until today.  When I boot up now, it goes straight into OS-X, whether or not I have the option keys pressed.  It still sees the other partitions when I go into the "Startup Disk" utility in the System Preferences.  I have done nothing with the boot sector, haven't even installed anything into the machine since the last time I booted into Windows.  Is there a simple fix that I am missing?  I really. REALLY do not want to install Windows again if I can at all help it.

I see that I can boot to windows through the Startup Disk mechanism, but that is really not workable as a long term solution.  Any thoughts on how to make this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual response to these types of issues is to do a PRAM/NVRAM reset: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379

There is a way to disable the option key through the [computer's 'low-level Firmware protection'](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1352), but I doubt this is the case.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!  PRAM was the problem - the sad part is that I knew about this at one point.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

IMHO I think you should install reFIT. Get it here: http://refit.sourceforge.net/

It's a kickass replacement bootloader for Macs, it will see your Windows partition, as well as any USB, CD, HD Operating System, regardless of vendor.

Check it out. Super easy to install.

Comment: +1 for sure this is a good replacement (we use it).